# Apply CSS class in stylesheet

Tags: css

Is there a way to apply a class to a set of nodes matching a CSS selector, inside the actual stylesheet?

This is of course possible in a single line of jquery, but is it possible to do in the css itself?

```
input[type='button']
{
// apply the class 'k-button' to these
}
```

Comment: Nope. But you can apply the same rules to that class by appending it with `, .k-button`

Comment: No, but look into [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). The concept of *mixins* lets you do something similar.

Comment: Seeing how Twitter Bootstrap implements LESS gave me a good understanding of these concepts.

Comment: You might be right @Jeroen. I'm using a widget framework (kendo ui) which has it's own styling when it uses buttons itself. I'm simply extending it's to the rest of my pages so for example I want to apply it's k-button style to buttons and so on for consistency. Just don't want to then have to change all my markup or add tedious js to maintain. I'll have to go the js route to apply the classes. I asked this because it would be the cleanest way to achieve.

Comment: @DanRevell Makes sense. If you ask a follow-up question that links to this one (to explain what you've tried) there may well be folks around that can help you with that X situation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to apply a class to a set of nodes matching a CSS selector, inside the actual stylesheet?

Nope, there's currently no way of doing that with standards compliant CSS.

Answer (score 0):

No,there is not way of attach class with css,but you can use this code with jquery

```
$(".YourClassName").addClass("YourNewClass");
```

best regards

Comment: *This is of course possible in a single line of jquery, but is it possible to do in the css itself?* - OP

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this with CSS. You're talking about altering markup, which CSS is really not designed to do (content: rules aside). As others have suggested, I would look into the 'extend' options in SASS, or use jQuery if need be.

That all being said - why can't you copy the relevant styles from the class declaration, and paste them into your selector? Or, just tack your selector on to the class declaration?

Comment: "why can't you copy the relevant styles from the class declaration, and paste them into your selector" - there are some situations where you have no real control over the HTML that you are trying to style, and are trying to apply a framework (like Bootstrap) to the auto-generated HTML. I ran into this problem when trying to use Bootstrap with an auto-generated Django form. I ended up using LESS, but this wasn't really ideal.